# Adding two columns results in concatenation instead of addition

Tags: ms-access, sum, concat

I need help using addition.  When I do it populates using the concatenate function.

I used the following in my access database Total: `[ANTI TERROR]+[Records]` and instead of returning `1 + 1 = 2` it returns `11` - i.e. it's using the concatenate function.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you should use the [type conversion function](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Type-Conversion-Functions-8ebb0e94-2d43-4975-bb13-87ac8d1a2202) `CInt()`?

As in, `CInt(expr1) + CInt(expr2)`.  Does this fix your problem?

This is necessary if you haven't defined the column data type as a numeric type.

Comment: Kindly mark the answer as correct so that those who have a similar problem can find an answer - I now that it takes some time before you can do this, but it will help others.